# 'SparkSession' object has no attribute 'databricks'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

New to databricks and spark, I'm trying to run the below command and met this error

```
spark.databricks.delta.retentionDurationCheck.enabled= "false"
```

error: `'SparkSession' object has no attribute 'databricks'`

Comment: This looks like a configuration. If its a SQL configuration, use `SET` command , otherwise use `--conf` to pass it to the Spark application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be as `sql`

```
spark.sql("SET spark.databricks.delta.retentionDurationCheck.enabled=false")
```

Or put it in as `spark Conf` property

Comment: Could you provide an example of specifying such a spark conf property?

Comment: @SamuelLampa - See if this helps : https://community.databricks.com/s/question/0D53f00001mIUHACA4/how-to-set-retention-period-for-a-delta-table-lower-than-the-default-period-is-it-even-possible

Comment: Many thanks @SMaZ . Yes, the syntax that in the above case would be: `spark.conf.set("databricks.delta.retentionDurationCheck.enabled", "false")` did indeed work!

Comment: ^needs to have spark in front of databricks as shown in link above `spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.retentionDurationCheck.enabled", "false")`